# Set all rows in SQL where id='$id'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have made an online Police Dispatching program and I am trying to add a new feature.
I want to add a button to set all Police Officer's status to 'On Duty'.
This is my current action for the form/submit button:

```
<?php

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET status='0' WHERE code='$code'");

mysqli_close($con);
printf("<script>location.href='../units.php'</script>");
?>
```

The 'On Duty' is the same as 0, busy is 1, and unavailable is 2.  The code is basically the Police Department's unique code that all Officers have.
Right now, this is affecting any rows!  Please help!

Comment: What is `$code`? Also is `status` an `int` or `varchar`?

Comment: Please show us your code?

Comment: I'm confused.... what exactly is the problem? and Using an UPDATE sql statement will affect rows if all conditions after WHERE are true.

Comment: `status` is `text`.  `$code` is the session saved unique police department id for the user

Comment: A) What does `$code` output. B) What are the values for code? C) Why is status `0` if it is text? `0` is an int or tinyint, what other values can be there? If there are others that can be text why not make it relational (each ID corresponds to another table with values to the ID and a text string in a separate column)?

Comment: It would help if you gave a dump of your database (at least the line(s) you expect to be modified), including the schema.

Comment: If your data is correct and code value is correct in the session than query is ok no issue with query. it look like more of a data problem can you post your data in and code value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want ALL to be set to Zero, as you say, just Drop your WHERE statement.

```
"UPDATE users SET status='0'";
```

You should drop the Single Quotes as well, but it's not hurting anything.

```
"UPDATE users SET status=0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Database has this security that don't allow users to update all data when you are using a UPDATE statement without WHERE clause, you can do a hacky query like this

```
UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE code != 'any value'; // if code is string

UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE code <> 0; // if integer, just makes sure 0 is not a code in your DB
```

all rows that didn't match in the value will be updated, in this case, all rows will be updated